# EF core 2 composite primary key using Id and a foreign key

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two model classes

```
    public class ClassA 
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }        

        public IEnumerable<ClassB> ClassBs { get; set; }

    }

    public class ClassB 
    {
        public String Id { get; set; }                

    }
```

How do I tell entity framework to create table ClassB with a composite primary key with ClassA.Id and ClassB.Id? That way I can have multiple records with the same Id in ClassB table.
I don't want to change ClassB to add another Guid Id property. I don't want to use EF attributes either, I'd like to keep the model class separated from the ORM framework.

Comment: `I don't want to change ClassB to add another Guid Id property. I don't want to use EF attributes either`-Please explain this further.

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: I'm exploring the possibility of adopting EF with existing code, would like to avoid changing current model if possible.

Comment: How would you do that without adding foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to introduce explicit FK property to `ClassB` model, you can utilize the non lambda overload of `HasKey` receinving `string` property names and pass the [shadow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) FK property name, which by convention for this model is "ClassAId":

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassB>()
    .HasKey("Id", "ClassAId");
```

One of the drawbacks of this method is the usage of "magic" strings. But it can be avoided with the help of `nameof` operator.

Another drawback is that the only way to retrieve/manipulate `ClassB` objects would be through parent `ClassA` object (although inside EF Core LINQ to Entities queries you can use `EF.Property<Guid>(param, "ClassAId")` to access it for filtering/ordering/projection if needed).

Answer (score 0):

Write your `ClassB` as follows:

```
public class ClassB 
{
    public String Id { get; set; }

    public Guid ClassAId {get; set;}

    ...............

    public ClassA ClassA  {get; set;}               

}
```

Then write the `ClassB` Configuration as follows:

```
public class ClassBConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ClassB>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ClassB> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(b => new { b.Id, b.ClassAId });

        builder.HasOne(b => b.ClassA).WithMany(a => a.ClassBs).HasForeignKey(b => b.ClassAId);
    }
}
```

Then in the `OnModelCreating` as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ClassBConfiguration());
}
```